# Azure AD DS on multiple Azure regions

Tags: azure, active-directory

We are currently using the following AD architecture for our production environment on Azure: our on premise AD is replicated through Azure connect to an Azure AD, on which we use Azure AD DS. All of the infra is currently in the same Azure region.

We are soon going to instanciate another production environment in another Azure region but we are now facing an AD architecture issue:

- we can't instanciate a new AD DS in this Azure region as we are limited at one per subscription
- we can't use the one that exists as an AD DS is limited to one VNET and the two regions are not eligible for VNET peering

I tried to create another subscription using the same AD but I wasn't able to instanciate an Azure AD DS on it either (says there is already one for this tenant...).

Now I can see a couple of options:

- Create a new domain using DC servers in the new region and do another replication through Azure connect
- Create a new Azure account and create a new Azure AD and do another replication...

So both options are not optimal at all...

Have you guys ever faced this requirement? What would be my options there?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, why are those regions not eligible for peering? i dont know about such regions. also, you can always use site-to-site vpn

Comment: Based on: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/region-expansion-global-vnet-peering/ one of my region (in Australia) is not listed there... However, I just found pricing for peering in that region... So that might be an option in the end. Thanks! I'll try to see if it works. I'm just a bit worried about the performances using an AD DS located on the other side of the world

Comment: depends on what you are doing, but unless you are doing rds farm with thousands of users should be fine

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that then :)